# With R package openxlsx i am trying to merge columns and rows. though script works it does not allow me to overwrite

Tags: r, merge, xlsx, readxl, openxlsx

I use this script

```
library(openxlsx)

Output <- read.xlsx(xlsxFile = "Excel_file.xlsx", fillMergedCells  = 
TRUE,colNames = TRUE)
```

When i do this it works and does what it is supposed to do. The file contains a lot of merged rows and columns. However it doesn't always work. Is there another package or another script i can do that maybe can do overwrite? I'm wondering if that is the issue.

Otherwise when i try to run the script above again it tells me.

```
Error in read.xlsx(xlsxFile = "Excel_file.xlsx", fillMergedCells = TRUE,  : 
Please provide a sheet name OR a sheet index.
```

when i do and acknowledge adding sheet name or sheet index.....

```
library(openxlsx) 
Output <- read.xlsx(xlsxFile = "Excel_file.xlsx", fillMergedCells  = TRUE,colNames = TRUE,sheetIndex = 1)
```

or

```
library(openxlsx) 
Output <- read.xlsx(xlsxFile = "Excel_file.xlsx", fillMergedCells  = TRUE,colNames = TRUE,sheetName = "sheet 1")
```

i get another error message

```
Error in loadWorkbook(file, password = password) : 
argument "file" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: did you provide the proper file path to the 'xlsxFile' argument?

Comment: I just provided it go to the project folder. I didn't write out an actual file path because normally by default it goes there.

Comment: whats your output of getwd() ; if its not the project folder, then the read.xlsx function wont work due to the false param